# How to seal gaps around door to prevent mosquitoes from entering?

Tags: doors, mosquitoes

I have gaps above and below the doors of my house, from which mosquitoes enter in huge numbers. I fold newspapers and fit them every day.
This takes a lot of time as I have to do it for every door.

Please give answer in consideration to the fact that I can only fix it at home itself as my city is under complete lock-down due to corona-virus

Sorry, I am not good at speaking English.

What can I do to stop them once and for all.

[this is a video in which you can see the problem with one of the doors](https://youtu.be/qLJ8Wh4oP5s)

Comment: If you could provide a picture of the whole door and a few to show some detail, the door may be in good enough shape to remove and reset.

Comment: @Jack thanks for the suggestion, I've added a video now

Comment: This looks like a metal, perhaps aluminum door? If there was anyway to get weather stripping applied, is all you need. I know the lockdown makes it difficult, but that is the proper fix.

Comment: That is crazy that mosquitos are going through such small gaps.   I have never experienced that and I once had a back yard full of mosquitoes with a backdoor that was old and gaps almost that you could see through.   Have you thought about putting a storm door on?

Comment: @Jack Yes. Well thanks, I should be thinking of making a weather strip at home somehow.

Comment: @DMoore My city has open drains in many places, so there's plenty of mosquitoes. Even after I seal all gaps, some of them somehow sneak their way in. I'll apply weather stripping or maybe get a storm door if it isn't enough after this corona menace ends.

Comment: Can you staple or nail cardboard or rolled-up fabric to the top/bottom?

Comment: If there was a way you could use the clear packing tape I think I seen in your video, you could attach it to the  jamb with something the right size to make a bead like weather stripping has, and attach the other edge so the bead or hump made would contact the door the same way weatherstripping does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have any kind of wide tape that can be applied like the blue lines suggest, that may help you. The door will to be free of dirt or dust so the tape will really stick good.

The one example on the corner with the brown and blue is the example I meant in the comment. The 2 other examples are tape stuck in place and folded back so it sticks to itself and the jamb again.

[image]

Comment: I can do this . Thanks jack

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you call a contractor to replace the door. You could go to Home Depot or Lowes or call a local window and door company to access your problem and give you a price to do the work. If the door itself is not the priblem then a more detailed description of the problem is needed.

Comment: I live in india, and we have complete lockdown at my place. Sorry I should've mentioned that earlier

Comment: Your answer is perfect though.